# ModalViewController only displays if animated

Tags: iphone, ios4, delegates, xcode4, modalviewcontroller

In my app delegate, I want to display a Sign Up Screen for application first start.

Here is my code :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
[[[self.tabBarController.tabBar items] objectAtIndex:2] setEnabled:NO];    
[[[self.tabBarController.tabBar items] objectAtIndex:3] setEnabled:NO]; 

if (![self checkAuth]) {
    SignupViewController * signUp = [[SignupViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SignupView" bundle:nil] ;
    [signUp setManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [[self tabBarController] presentModalViewController:signUp animated:YES] ;
    [signUp release] ;
}
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;}
```

Everything works fine, but I don't want my modalViewController to be animated...

When I change the line :

```
[[self tabBarController] presentModalViewController:signUp animated:YES] ;
```

for :

```
[[self tabBarController] presentModalViewController:signUp animated:NO] ;
```

My underlying tabBarController is displayed and my modalViewController does not appear !

I spent a lot of time to search someone with a similar problem, but I didn't found any solution...

Someone can help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to call `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];` before presentModalViewController.

Comment: I suppose with animated==YES there is a little delay while presenting the modalView which makes the window visible before really adding the modalView. If animated==NO the modalView will be added while window is not visible and is ignored.